# Win7: Arrange multiple Screens in non-rectangular pattern?

Tags: windows-7, display

I'm using an ATI FirePro with 6 x MiniDP outs, and I need to arrange the screens in the following pattern:

```
(S1)(S2)(S3)(S6)
    (S4)(S5)
```

Is it possible to get Windows to accept it? Apparently it only likes rectangular setups (so either 3x2 oder 2x3 screens)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I would bet that if you use the AMD Vision Engine Control Center then you should be able to get the desired results. I believe AMD pretty much pioneered the technology (eyefinity) and everyone else is playing catch-up, even Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Nope.. you should be able to arrange your desktop in any way you like.

I've done arrangement where a laptop + 2 external screen goes like

```
(S1)  (S2)
   (L1)
```

Where L1 is the laptop screen, and you go "up-left" for screen 1, and up-right for screen 2.

I don't know about using the AMD tools, but windows 7 (Right click on Desktop - Screen Resolution) allows you to do it.